# Unity-XCode Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 or Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, iphone-5

I did a project in Unity and try to compile it for iOS. The compilation in Unity is going well. Then, I try to compile in xCode and get the 7 errors all from this type:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "__SetUnitySignalToReadVector3ArrayDelegatePointer", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "__FillVector3ArrayByRef", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "__SetUnityCommandDelegatePointer", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "__SetUnityLogDelegatePointer", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "__SetUnityIsReady", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "__CallLogOnNative", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

According to many discussions I should change the Architectures and Valid Architecture in Build Setting to Armv6 instead of Armv7.

I did it and gladly the compilation end successfully. But, then, when trying to run it on my iPhone 5, I get the following massage:

> Xcode cannot run using the selected device. Choose a destination with
>   a supported architecture in order to run on this device.

How can I make this to compiled successfully in xCode and in the same time run on iPhone 5?

Comment: what's the minimum deployment target? If you set this to iOS 8 but the iPhone 5 has only iOS 7 installed you'll get the same message.

Comment: It is set to iOS 7.1 and my iOS version is 7.1.2

Comment: How did you change to armv6 ?